# strace vs web browser

Tags: process, socket, strace

I was trying to `strace` an `iceweasel` like this:

```
strace -e trace=connect iceweasel
```

And I was expecting to see calls to `connect` when I load new pages. Surprisingly, there weren't any.

Why so? Am I using `strace` incorrectly or why doesn't it show calls to `connect` which obviously must happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iceweasel creates a lot of child processes, which then do the connection to remote web servers. You have to advice `strace` to also trace childs, when the binary executes the `fork()` system call to create a child.

Use this command:

```
strace -f -e trace=connect iceweasel
```